# Using @media print for IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

Recently i began a new job, and one thing i noticed in their boilerplate is that on their CSS, the print styles are separated into a diff file. I asked about the reasoning and was told IE8 doesnt support @media print.

Now, for the last couple of years i've worked on a couple of sites, where IE8 was supported and which required print support. And i've always included the print styles using the @media print method. The funny thing, is that print works using this method. Any idea why ? Now that i think about it, if @media print is not supported on IE8, but the print styles are working on my projects, where is the catch?

By the way, the project im referring to, where the print styles are working on IE8 is this one: http://news.hydroquebec.com/en/press-releases/704/addenergie-will-supply-the-fast-charge-stations/?fromSearch=1

Could it be the printshiv ?

Answer (score 1):

IE8 supports `@media print` just fine. `print` by itself is just a [media type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) and not a full-fledged media query, which old versions of IE understand just fine and has worked on all browsers for over a decade.

Nothing to do with printshiv — while it provides fixes for rendering HTML5 elements to print, that is a separate thing from `@media print` entirely.

Comment: That is what i imagine. Its just that at my new job that was the reasoning behind having Print styles loaded separately.

Comment: @Pablo Rincon: That is simply for code organization, I think, and has nothing to do with browser compatibility. If they state otherwise, then they've misunderstood.